# ADBC temporary table in HANA

Tags: database, performance, hana

I have created a temporary table using ADBC in ABAP and fill them with the required datas instead of using internal table because of the performance issues due to large data that we are processing for the reports. After processing I always drop the temporary table that I have created. My question is, will there be any problem in the server if we will often use this method?

Like when 100 employees used the program which process 350,000+ records in the same time would that be bad for the server?
Please enlighten me.

Thanks in advance!

edit :
The records will be displayed in ALV

Here's the code :
**tmp_table** is the variable for the temporary table name 
**autoid** is the variable for the sequence name

```
   sql->execute_ddl( |CREATE SEQUENCE { autoid } | &&
                      |START WITH    00001    | &&
                      |INCREMENT BY   1       | ).

    crte_txt = | CREATE TABLE { tmp_table } |  &&
               |( bid bigint NOT NULL ,   | && 
               |  contract char(50) ,     | && 
               |  swenr char(50),         | && 
               |  smenr CHAR(8),          | &&
               |  saltnr char(20),        | &&
               |  bp char(10),            | && 
               |  spsbp char(10),         | && 
               |  organization char(255), | && 
               |  n_first char(100),      | &&
               |  n_last char(100),       | && 
               |  n_mid char(100),        | && 
               |  addrnumber char(10),    | && 
               |  address char(1250),     | && 
               |  addr_type char(30),     | && 
               |  adr_kind char(10),      | && 
               |  email char(100),        | && 
               |  email2 char(100),       | && 
               |  wsl number(23,2),       | && 
               |  belnr char(10),         | && 
               |  belnr2 varchar(10),     | && 
               |  xblnr char(16),         | &&
               |  gjahr char(4),          | &&
               |  buzei char(3),          | &&
               |  pdescript char(120) null, | &&
               |  vbewa char(4),          | &&
               |  qbshb number(23,2),     | &&
               |  wrbtr1 number(23,2),    | &&
               |  wrbtr2 number(23,2),    | &&
               |  bktxt char(25),         | &&
               |  sgtxt char(50),         | &&
               |  checkno char(20),       | &&
               |  checkamnt number(23,2), | &&
               |  checkdate date,         | &&
               |  receiptdate date,       | &&
               |  role char(6),           | &&
               |  abp char(10),           | && 
               |  intreno char(30),       | &&
               |  agn_first char(100),    | && 
               |  agn_last char(100),     | && 
               |  agn_mid char(100),      | && 
               |  agn_org char(255),      | && 
               |  jv char(10),            | &&
               |  validfrom date,         | &&
               |  validto date,           | &&
               |  objnr char(22),         | &&
               |  condtype char(4),       | &&
               |  unitprice number(23,6), | &&
               |  termnopy char(4),       | &&
               |  ccnetamount number(15,2), | &&
               |  cctaxamount number(15,2), | &&
               |  condguid raw(16),      | &&
               |  PRIMARY KEY (bid) )     | .

 text = | INSERT INTO { dbbuyr } ( bid, contract, bp, addrnumber, adr_kind, swenr, smenr) | &&
             | SELECT ({ autoid }.nextval) as key, a.recnnr AS contract, b.partner AS bp, c.addrnumber, | &&
             | c.adr_kind, e.swenr, e.smenr | &&
             | FROM vicncn AS a | &&
             | INNER JOIN vibpobjrel AS b ON a.intreno = b.intreno | &&
             | INNER JOIN but021_fs AS c ON b.partner = c.partner  | &&
             | INNER JOIN jest AS d ON a.objnr = d.objnr| &&
             | INNER JOIN v_recncne as e on a.recnnr = e.recnnr |  &&
             | WHERE a.recndactiv <> 00000000 | &&
             | AND ( a.recntype = 'ZC01' OR a.recntype = 'ZC02' ) | &&
             | AND b.validfrom <= | && sy-datum && | AND b.validto >=  | && sy-datum &&
             | AND b.role IN ({ cond_role }) | && "( b.role = 'ZBP101' OR b.role = 'ZBP301' ) | &&
             | AND c.valid_to >= | && tmstmp && | AND c.valid_from <= | && tmstmp &&
             | AND d.stat IN ({ cond_stat }) | &&"= 'I0119' | &&
*             | AND e.swenr = '{ swenr }' | &&
             | { sw_cond } { re_cond } { sm_cond } | &&
             | AND e.validto >= { sy-datum } AND e.validfrom <= { sy-datum }| &&
             | AND a.mandt = b.mandt AND b.mandt = c.client AND c.client = d.mandt | &&
             | AND d.mandt = e.mandt AND e.mandt =  { sy-mandt } | .


      sql->execute_update( CONV #( text ) ).
```

There's alot of update statement after this to fetch the other datas

```
sql->execute_ddl( |DROP SEQUENCE { autoid } | ). 
  sql->execute_ddl( |DROP TABLE { tmp_table } | ).
```

Comment: You use ADBC to directly operate on the database. So, your question concerns only the database system you are using, not ABAP. Please edit the **tags** accordingly.

Comment: Could you post all the SQL queries you are using? (at least INSERT and DROP based on your question) Don't post the ABAP code, it's not concerned by your question.

Comment: Hi, I have made an edit. Do you think this will affect the server, in terms of memory, space or etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code does **not** create a temporary table as a database object.
Instead, it creates a regular table and a sequence.

While such code can work it is hardly necessary and comes with several drawbacks.

1. The table name has to be made unique in order to avoid collisions with parallel running instances of the code.
2. Since this is a regular database table (and not a *temporary table* this table will be covered in the database catalog and in the transaction handling. That means, it will create redo logs, which is completely unnecessary, as this table never will have to be recovered.
3. As your system runs on HANA you can use Database Managed Procedures to perform mass data processing. Effectively, you can use HANA SQLScript including **table variables** in your procedure.
   With table variables HANA does not need to create an in-memory table
   structure does not need to handle a changing table name, does not
   keep track of multiple sessions using the same table, etc.
   Using table variables is the far better approach here.
4. Creating a sequence object is utter nonsense to simply enumerate records in your intermediate result set. 
   To achieve that, you can simply use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function.
5. Since your current code also destroys the created objects after processing, all parsed SQL statements will be invalidated. and new parsing/compiling of the statements will be required the next time the code gets executed.
6. With the `CREATE TABLE` statement, the code does not specify, whether this should be a COLUMN or ROW table. As this has considerable consequences in HANA (you nearly always want a COLUMN table) it is **highly** recommendable, to specify this. With HANA 1 and HANA 2 CREATE TABLE without table type specification will create a ROW table.  Don't leave that to chance.

You mentioned, that the actual processing code will run `UPDATEs` against the intermediate table. In the vast majority of cases, an `UPDATE` can be replaced by a `SELECT` and assignment to a new table variable.
This usually leads to much cleaner and faster code and avoids a *"row-by-row/slow-by-slow"* processing.

So, yes, the current code will negatively affect end-user performance and server resource utilization.

Comment: Hello Lars, Actually it was way more faster than using internal table and open sql when fetching a lot of records. Is there any other way that I can still use this and prevent the drawbacks.

Comment: Not surprised that your approach was still faster than copying the data to the App-Server process. But my point was to use SQLSCRIPT table variables. These live only in the HANA process & are very different from ABAP internal tables.

Comment: Is there any other way to prevent the drawbacks from using that method in ADBC? Can we prevent it from creating redo logs? And regarding the SQLSCRIPT table variables, can i use that in abap netweaver?

Comment: I mean sap netweaver. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can write HANA procedures from the ABAP environment. The way to do that is called *AMDP* ABAP Managed DB Procedures. There’s plenty of documentation on that on help.sap.com.